# Any way to redirect HTTP traffic from one PC to another

Tags: c#, http, networking, socks, tunnel

I have some bit of code running in lets say machine A which does some simple HTTP calls to a application deployed in AWS EC2. I need the HTTP calls to be routed from machine A to another PC which we refer to as machine B.The catch is that the HTTP traffic need to pass through a custom made network interface in machine B rather that the default Ethernet interface already present.

I am little confused at this point and have some faint idea that a SOCKS proxy or HTTP tunnel might be the way to go.Any suggestions will helpful.Thank you.

PS:Machine A -> Windows PC Machine B-> running Linux.

Comment: Looks like machine A is a two port application with one port accepting clients and the 2nd port a connection to machine B.  If you are running linux than you probably want to send messages over TCP Ethernet, just not in HTTP format.  I would use a TCP connection for the Windows to Linux connection to machine B.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Custom Made Interface' ? A must be connected to B through Bluetooth/WIFI/Ethernet ?? How A and B are connected physically if not ethernet?